# Remove AD Connect (no connection avaiable to on prem)

Tags: azure, azureadconnect

Whilst on a Windows Server 2016 course we created domain and setup AD Connect inside a lab. Unfortunately, the lab has since been wiped and now I'm getting emails daily regarding ad sync issues. Is there a way for me to remove AD Connect without having access to the "on prem" DC? I wouldn't mind keeping my Azure subscription as I plan on studying a little more about it.

Cheers in advance.

Cheers,

Luke.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/turn-off-directory-synchronization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after a while I stopped receiving these emails from Microsoft.